# How to do a EntityFramework query against md5 of a column

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

How can I perform this query using entity framework (linq or lambda) :

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE md5(email) = '9d6e1c44328f4d628ffb0cacbe6b5c44';
```

this is a simplified example query not the actual problem.

the database is MySQL and I'm using mysqlconnector 6.7.4

Comment: Just to clarify: the hash is not stored in the database, correct? If so, could you add a hash field? That would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: no, the hash is not stored and I would love to avoid storing it... but I see your point.

Comment: The problem is that EF doesn't inherently know about database functions for any dbms. So any solution short of an sql query through EF is going to be fairly messy and probably not worth the time it would take, compared to just storing the email hash in a separate column. Otherwise you could bring the entire resultset into memory and do the hash comparison entirely in code, but that could be really inefficient depending on the size of your users table.

Comment: I see, so options are storing the hash, create a normal sql query using EF or Stored Procedure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this;

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery<your_user_class>("SELECT * FROM user WHERE md5(email) = '9d6e1c44328f4d628ffb0cacbe6b5c44';");
```